# Zend_Gdata_Calendar_EventEntry answers in German

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-calendar-api

My problem is that all responses of **Zend_Gdata_Calendar_EventEntry** are sent to my application in German, I guess because it takes the server language automatically. I would like to know how to force GData's language?

This is a part of my application's code:

```
//on récupère le nom du service
$this->gcal = Zend_Gdata_Calendar::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;

//on s'authentifie
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $this->gcal);
$client->setConfig(array('language' => 'en'));

//on crée un nouvel objet calendar
$this->gcal = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);
```

If I print my GCal object, the language is set in English. I don't understand why Google answers in German!

Comment: is it just EventEntry? Try to var_dump the $this->getReponse, see if there are any clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Google may be doing something that we can do in ZF:

> There are three locales which have a slightly different behaviour:
>
> 'browser' - Zend_Locale should work with the information which is
>   provided by the user's Web browser. It is published by PHP in the
>   global variable $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].
>
> If a user provides more than one locale within his browser,
>   Zend_Locale will use the first found locale. If the user does not
>   provide a locale or the script is being called from the command line
>   the automatic locale 'environment' will automatically be used and
>   returned.
>
> 'environment' - Zend_Locale should work with the information which is
>   provided by the host server. It is published by PHP via the internal
>   function setlocale().
>
> If a environment provides more than one locale, Zend_Locale will use
>   the first found locale. If the host does not provide a locale the
>   automatic locale 'browser' will automatically be used and returned.
>
> 'auto' - Zend_Locale should automatically detect any locale which can
>   be worked with. It will first search for a users locale and then, if
>   not successful, search for the host locale.
>
> If no locale can be detected, it will throw an exception and tell you
>   that the automatic detection has been failed.

your server may be setting $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] to DE, I know it's not much but at least you can check and maybe change it in app.